# Perl Gnuplot inline Histogram

Tags: perl, gnuplot

I am trying to feed the output of a 2x column hash to a simple barchart using gnuplot.

For some reason it doesnt like something about my hash, or for some reason the inline data is not correct.  I only get the first row and it throws a few errors.

```
open my $out,'|-','gnuplot';
say $out 'unset key';
say $out 'set auto x';
say $out 'set ylabel "Fail Count"';
say $out "set style histogram gap 5";
say $out "plot '-' using 2:xtic(1)";
foreach (keys %fail_counts) {
  if ($fail_counts{$_} > 1) {
    say $out "$_  $fail_counts{$_} "; 
  }  
}
say $out 'e';
flush $out;
<STDIN>;
close $out;
```

Here is what my hash looks like:

blah1 8
blah2 8
blah3 65
blah4 39
blah5 23
blah6 12

Errors:
Warning: empty x range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1]
Warning: empty y range [8:8], adjusting to [7.92:8.08]

Here is how the hash is populated, its just a tabulation of individual rows of fail data:

```
#sum and plot the categories
%fail_counts = ();
foreach $fail (@fail_array) {
  @temp_array=split/\s+/,$fail;  
  if (exists $fail_counts{$temp_array[4]}) {
    $fail_counts{$temp_array[4]} = $fail_counts{$temp_array[4]} + 1;
  } else {
    $fail_counts{$temp_array[4]} = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show how you populate the hash and what it really contains. When I prepend `my %fail_counts = qw( blah1 8 blah2 8 blah3 65 blah4 39 blah5 23 blah6 12 );` to the script, it works correctly.

Comment: Well, your range is off so you just don't get to see all points (except for the 8).  also, what are "blah"s for the x-axis?

Comment: I used blah's to obfuscate the actual data which is probably confidential ;)  Updated original with how the hash is formed...

Comment: @zdim can you elaborate on my range?  I have seen so many examples of histograms and none of them have been very clear with how you identify the rows and columns.  I don't specify any range specifically other than auto x?

Comment: You get a warning `empty y range [8:8], adjusting to [7.92:8.08]` so it seemed to me that out of data you show only those with y==8 are used/shown. (I rarely used histograms in gnuplot so please check this.) Perhaps you want to set ranges anyway, given the warnings (while I wouldn't expect that you'd _have to_ do that for histograms). But @choroba ran this and it worked so maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like there are extra characters in the hash as seen by @choroba